# Do We Answer Claims or the Arguments They Come From?

Tags: discussion, answers

I'm new to Skeptics.SE, coming from other .SE sites.  Questions here often seem to have two components: a broad argument and a specific claim.  My understanding is that a good answer authenticates or verifies the specific claim (which is often a matter of fact), rather than the broad argument (which may not be).

Is that the style here?

One Example:
[Who Writes Congressional Bills?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/13850/who-writes-congressional-bills?noredirect=1#comment119507_13850)

The narrow question is something like "who writes bills in Congress", while the larger argument is about who influences the content of bills.  I opted to answer what looks like the factual claim ("Who writes bills?" The Office of Legislative Council does), but I'm getting some feedback that suggests I should be tackling the larger argument the claim comes from.

Comment: Your answer has 6 upvotes! Looks like people like it.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm also trying to make sure I understand the conventions of this SE site :)

Comment: Me too :) So far, I'm thinking that you don't need to worry about comments very much.